# how to make dynamic uitableview cells look like that of static uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, dynamic, static

I find static uitableview aesthetically impressive than the flat dynamic uitableview. Is there a way to make the uitableview with dynamic cells also look like that of static uitableview in terms of looks?? Thanks!!

[image: dynamic uitableview]

[image: static uitableview]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes select your dynamic tableview go to the 4th tab on the right. Next to style select grouped.

Comment: thank you @Abdullah Shafique..but I have implemented many subviews inside each cell and now all of them got displaced..after selecting grouped..is there a way to get them aligned or should I just align them myself in the code?

Comment: also, the cell width seems to have dropped..it has reduced and doesnt fit the uitableview i drew on the storyboard..is this its natural effect?

Comment: @KedariTheja Yes that is what grouped cells do.